# Count number of word occurrences working slow BaseX xquery

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0, xquery-3.1

I want to count occurrences of the words in the XML document, query giving the actual count but it is working slow.

There are only two xml files size (236 KB, 155 KB) and it is taking 17 sec to produce result.

Below is the query:

```
let $doc := db:open('test','/ieee/test.xml')

let $tokens := $doc//text()/fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space(.),'\s')
let $stringtoken := for $x at $pos in $tokens[position() = 1 to fn:last()-1]
                    let $y := string-join($tokens[position() = $pos to $pos + 1],' ')
                    return $y
return                  
<results>
        {
          for $result in distinct-values($stringtoken)
          let $count := count($stringtoken[. = $result])
          return
         <term word="{$result}" count="{$count}"></term>
        }
</results>
```

In  the above query let $count := count($stringtoken[. = $result]) is taking too much time.

Any suggestion to improve the performance of the code much appreciated.

Comment: By `$tokens[position() = $pos to $pos + 1]`, you are creating combinations of two adjacent tokens, but this is not indicated in the text. Could you further specify this?

Comment: Thank for your response @christian, Yes I  am creating combination of two adjacent

Comment: Is your suggested query speed up?

Comment: So Here I would like to give preference to user if user paas parameters 0 then it will find and count one word, where is +1 i am using for combination of two adjacent user can increase the number instead of +1 it could be +2 so it that case three combination

Comment: The proposed `group by` clause should make it much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` statement will speed up your query a lot:

```
return <results>{
  for $grouped-token in $stringtoken
  group by $token := $grouped-token
  let $count := count($grouped-token)
  return <term word="{ $token }" count="{ $count }"/>
}</results>
```

Comment: Thank you Christian,  it is really too fast, you made my life easy!!! Thanks again.